# what is the difference between 135B Violin String and 135 Violin String?

Tags: strings, violin

I need to buy a string and my instructor has recommended me to buy a [dominant string](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Thomastik-Dominant-135B-Violin-String-Set-4-4-Size-/172259247169?hash=item281b738441:g:JsEAAOSwJblXAPF0). I noticed there are at least two types,

- Thomastik Dominant 135B Violin String Set 4/4 Size
- Thomastik Dominant 135 Violin String Set 4/4 Size

what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two is in the composition of the ball-end of the E-string:

> Thomastik Dominant violin strings are available with aluminum wound
> ball end E strings (set 135), with chrome steel ball end E strings
> (set 135B), and with chrome steel loop end E strings (set 135BMS)

http://www.juststrings.com/dominantthomastikinfeldviolin.html